# How to have a translation service in android app

Tags: android, translate

How can a translation service be called in an Android app?  Can we have an app that can translate multiple languages into another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Edit -** Google have deprecated the Translation API due to "misuse".  [Apertium](http://www.apertium.org/) is a possible alternative.

You asked:

> How can a translation service be called in an Android app?

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) would seem to be the obvious service to use in an Android App.

There is [an unofficial Java client API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/) you could use in your application to make the calls to Google Translate.

If you use this, make sure you give your application [the `INTERNET` permission](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) so it can make the appropriate network connections.

> Can we have an app that can translate multiple languages into another?

It's definitely possible to create an Android app to do this because [Google already have made a Google Translate application](http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.google.android.apps.translate/), as have [lots of other people](http://www.cyrket.com/search?q=google+translate+android).

Comment: Let me try this out. And i'll let you know

Comment: Google deprecated [Translation API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html) as part of their API spring cleaning May 26, 2011. This was announced in their blog post [Spring cleaning for some of our APIs](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html). It will be shut off completely on December 1, 2011.

Answer (score 1):

considering the fact that this answer I am posting is quite late,but it could help other.
first thing google has deprecated translater api version 1,and the version 2 it has launched comes under paid service.here is a link from bing which is totally free and has given complete steps to use it in your application.http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class to easily translate text based on google-api-translate.  All you have to do is get the device's locale and you can easily translate any text to the devices current language setting.  See [android-translate-api](http://code.google.com/p/android-translate-api/)