# Localizations: converting english text to Chinese text

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have a translation service in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325547/how-to-have-a-translation-service-in-android-app)

I am having one text view with some text like " This is a simple statement "
I am having one button view. if i click this button then the text available in text view should change to Chinese language.
How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [Google Translate API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html), but turns out they're turning it off this December due to abuse.

Answer (score 0):

Hire a person (who preferably speaks both English and Chinese reasonably) to translate the text and save it in a document.  You can then load this document into the view at the click of the button.

Alternatively, you can query translate.google.com for potentially hilarious results.

Comment: Lol :) such a funny trick .. Hahhaa